# How to combine array via PHP [hierarchy]

Tags: php, arrays

I have a incomprehensible task, please help solve the problem.
Мy array is now:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [Tomato] => Array
            (
                [Apple] => Array
                    (
                        [Orange] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Tomato] => Array
            (
                [Apple] => Array
                    (
                        [Orange] => Array
                            (
                                [Lemon] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Tomato] => Array
            (
                [Apple] => Array
                    (
                        [Pumpkin] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

How to combine all the values, in a single array, as a result:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [Tomato] => Array
            (
                [Apple] => Array
                    (
                        [Orange] => Array
                            (
                                [Lemon] => Array()
                            )
                        [Pumpkin] => Array()

                    )

            )

    )
```

I do not know how many will be nesting level in the main array, but first item is **Tomato** 
 The main problem is to combine similar items and leave them at their level in the hierarchy 
I will be glad to receive any help.

Comment: Is there a reason to use nested arrays like this? Looks like a huge complexification of data structure

Comment: Nordenheim, it is only for understanding, I'm going through the training

Comment: AmazingDream, you are absolutely right - homework from my customer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has a function just for you:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php

> array_merge_recursive() merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the resulting array.

In your case it appears you have a giant array, and you want to merge the sub arrays.

So maybe something like this:

```
$merged = [];
foreach($myGiantArray as $subArray) {
    $merged = array_merge_recursive($merged, $subArray);
}
```

This will merge each one of your sub arrays into one final `$merged` array.

Working example: https://3v4l.org/HuE0l

Comment: This is clearly not the answer. Or provide a working example

Comment: @Nordenheim maybe give me just a couple seconds to finish building out my answer? The PHP function pointed him in the right direction, and I just added a code example.

Comment: @Nordenheim and now I have a working example link, showing the output matches what the OP wants. Perhaps this would be a good time to reverse your downvote??

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!